# Read raw video stream from Android box HDMI input

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat

I am writing an app for android boxes (not Android TV), that have HDMI input port.

Is it possible to read raw video stream from HDMI or USB input and display it in android videoView ?

Here is the [link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Tronsmart-Pavo-M9-MSTAR-Quad-Core-Android-TV-BOX-1G-8G-4K-H-265-USB3-0/32653500882.html?spm=2114.30010308.3.2.RYWrF9&ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_0,searchweb201602_4_10057_10056_10065_10068_10055_9982_10054_10069_10059_10058_418_10073_10017_10070_10060_10061_10052_10062_10053_10050_10051,searchweb201603_1&btsid=2cff171b-208c-41ec-ac87-116432528b97) to the android box I am using. It uses API level 19 (Android 4.4).

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? I'm working with a Zidoo X9S. Looking forward to your answer!

Comment: This link (https://github.com/zidootech/ZidooDigitalSignage) would be useful to you. I have ordered Zidoo 8 last week, will update you once I receive it and get it working.